# SQL DELETE statement syntax

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-delete

Trying to execute a delete query and getting the following error

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'cname VALUES @cname'.

code

```
Dim conn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & My.Settings.strFileName)
conn.Open()
Dim cmdText = "DELETE FROM products WHERE cname VALUES @cname"
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(cmdText, conn)
With cmd.Parameters
  .Add(New OleDbParameter("@cname", DataGridView1.Item("cname", i).Value))
End With
Dim dt As New DataTable("products")
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
conn.Close()
conn = Nothing
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you wrote your delete statement is not correct.

You should write it like this:

```
Dim cmdText = "DELETE FROM products WHERE cname = @cname"
```

Answer (score 4):

You need an operator

```
DELETE FROM products WHERE cname = @cname
```

Answer (score -1):

And to `delete all` record from a table with a specific `ID`, you just have to;

```
deleteMore:
DELETE TOP(100) TableName WHERE toDelete='17'
IF @@ROWCOUNT != 0
    goto deleteMore:
```

This will delete the first 100 records, and repeatedly until all records with `17` are gone.